# A Mistake in my Codecademy Codebit, Not Sure What

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I do NOT have code here, as for it is going to take up ***too*** much space. It is an error in JavaScript as for it won't run anything in it, aswell as jQuery.

[Click here if you wanna live...](http://www.codecademy.com/bubster20/codebits/msfzsg/edit)

Comment: Do you have a more specific error?  Can you say what it is intended to do?

Comment: Also: `why_is_this_here`, `thisIsUseless`, and `lol` are poor variable names.  Try and use names which describe the intended purpose

Comment: OK: This is a program for a developmental custom language, it has the source, changes thinks like ?Bracket? and ?Paren? to (( and ( and shows the scripting code.

Comment: Ah, I understand the snark then, haha.  Gotta love CodeCademy

Comment: JSFiddle only runs it? I've heard that a lot.

Comment: Hi Matthew, unfortunately it is a **requirement** that you put your code in the question here. If you feel it is *too long*, then you should work to isolate the problem. Also, your question is too vague to answer currently:. Can you rephrase your question to be more clear? With that being said, Stack Overflow is *not* a good site for debugging why your code doesn't match the expected output of a code tutorial site.

Comment: Do you know how to debug JavaScript code? It sounds like that is the next skill you need to learn. Your web browser has debugging tools built into it. Take the time to explore those tools and use them to step through your JavaScript code to see what it is doing. You don't have to be mystified when your code doesn't work, you can use the developer tools to show you what it is actually doing. Here is [an introduction to the Chrome DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here I think:

`.replace('function mName1()'),('?Method??-Custom?','function')`

that comma needs to be a period and I'm guessing `replace` needs called.

`.replace('function mName1()').replace('?Method??-Custom?','function')`